How to track GPU usage of my iOS application?
Is it possible to track the instant GPU usage of my iOS application?
Xcode (I am using Xcode 15.4) provides the CPU, memory, network, FPS etc. But GPU is not included.
There is a similar question without answer: Programmatically get GPU usage in iOS. But I still want to try again.

How about using Instruments?

There is not a template for GPU tracking. In Metal System Trace, there is a category as GPU. But I don't quite think it provides the information about the percentage of GPU capability in use.
